# Difference of using "Register for COM Interop" vs "regasm.exe xxxx.dll /tlb:xxxx.tlb"?

Tags: c#, com-interop

Could someone explain me the difference between "Register for COM Interop" vs `"regasm.exe xxxx.dll /tlb:xxxx.tlb"`.

As per my understanding "Register for COM Interop" do generate a .tlb file and "regasm.exe xxxx.dll /tlb:xxxx.tlb" will generate a .tlb file as well. Do we need to use both the things or any one is fine to generate a tlb file.

Answer (score 3):

It is a convenience, aimed to make it as easy as possible to get this right while developing and debugging the library without having to run Regasm by hand.  It does the exact same thing as Regasm.exe /codebase /tlb does.  Where /codebase ensures that don't have to put the assembly in the GAC and /tlb ensures that you have an up-to-date type library for use in the client or testing code.  Both important on a dev machine, not on the user's machine.

But does two things that programmers often overlook when they run Regasm by hand.  You can't forget to use it, it is not always obvious exactly when re-registering is required.  And the big one, it does what Regasm.exe /unregister does to ensure that the old version of the library gets unregistered automatically before the new one is built.  Very easy to overlook, the registry pollution caused by this is not pretty to clean up afterwards.

When you explicitly apply the [Guid] attribute on the interfaces, classes and AssemblyInfo.cs then it matters a lot less since the registry keys are the same.  But you should only ever do that when you need to develop a drop-in replacement for an existing COM server.  The [Guid] attribute is holy, good COM practices demand that it is changed whenever you make a change in the public interface of the library.  Not doing so is very likely to cause DLL Hell.  The CLR takes care of this automatically when [Guid] is missing.

One disadvantage, you must run VS elevated so it can write to the registry.